# Help understanding this sentence about why some shrines remove their bells at busy times e.g. 正月

Tags: grammar, meaning

The character is explaining why some shrines remove their bell at times where many people gather at the shrine e.g. 正月. However I do not understand what he is saying.

**大人数で引っ張ると、落としちゃうやつとか出てきて危ないからな**

大人数で引っ張ると - I am assuming that 引っ張る is referring to the action of pulling some sort of rope in order to ring the bell. When he says 大人数で, does he mean this as in many people pulling the rope at the same time (i.e. together), or does it mean more like, when there are many people pulling this rope (individually) when it is their turn.

My next question is how to understand 落としちゃうやつとか出てきて危ない, specifically 落としちゃうやつ. I am assuming that やつ is referring to the person that makes 'something' fall, however I am not really quite sure what they could be referring to. I mean, the logical assumption (assuming I am understanding correctly) of something that would be dangerous if it fell would be the bell, however I am not sure if my understanding is correct. Are they saying that with so many people pulling the the rope, one of the might cause the bell to fall down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your understanding of the sentence is basically correct.

For the part of 「大人数で」, it is natural to think they ring the bell in their turn and throw some coins into the offertory box to make a wish for the new year at a shrine on 正月{しょうがつ}. I suppose it is not like [trevi fountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trevi_Fountain#Coin%20throwing) where many people throw coins at the same time around the water fountain.

For the part of 「落としちゃうやつ」, I think you parse it correctly as 落としちゃう + やつ.

~しちゃう is a casual form of ~してしまう, which means something happens irrelevantly to the speaker's intention.

So, the bell ends up falling sometimes even if shrine visitors do not mean to cause it by ringing the bell.

やつ here is used to refer to the person who causes the bell to fall. Probably the author wants to call them an unlucky person.